# Integrate Google Play Games + Google Maps extending BaseGamesActivity and FragmentActivity

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-games

I'm creating an application that uses Google maps to locate and display the current location of the user and some markers.

I would like to implement a check in part that will give points to the users and unlock achievements.

But I don't know how to extend both `BaseGameActivity` and `FragmentActivity`. A few hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha, a classic case of Activity superclass wars. Precisely with this problem in mind, we offer [`GameHelper`](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples/blob/master/libraries/BaseGameUtils/src/com/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper.java) as an alternative to `BaseGameActivity`, for games that for one reason or another cannot (or don't want to) change their Activity's base class. All you have to do is create a `GameHelper` object on your Activity's `onCreate` method and then let it know of important Activity lifecycle events, notably `onStop`, `onStart` and `onActivityResult`.

Take a look at the source code for [`BaseGameActivity`](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples/blob/master/libraries/BaseGameUtils/src/com/google/example/games/basegameutils/BaseGameActivity.java) as a reference. What you'll want to do is implement that same functionality in your Activity class so that you have a working `GameHelper`.

Particularly, you'll notice that `BaseGameActivity` is actually pretty dumb -- it just forwards events to `GameHelper`, which is really the brains behind it.